# Pyspark, find all the data types of a column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am doing some data cleaning and data profiling work. So the given data could be quite messy.

I want to get all the potential data types of a column using pyspark.
Data types like:

1. Integer
2. Real number
3. Date/Time
4. String (Text)
5. etc

I will need to do more processing to generate the respective metadata based on what types do the column has.

A column can contain more than one type. I don't mean the built-in data types. The given data are all of type `string`, but some are in the form of `"1234"` which is actually an `int`, and some are in the form of `"2019/11/19"`, which is actually a `date`.

For example, the column `number` could contain values like

- `"123"`
- `"123.456"`
- `"123,456.789"`
- `"NUMBER 123"`

In the above example, the data types would be `INTEGER, REAL NUMBER, STRING`.

If I used `df.schema[col].dataType`, it just simply give me StringType.

I was thinking that I can iterate through the entire column, and use `regex` to see which type does the row belong to, but I am curious if there is some better way to do it, since it's a relatively large dataset.

---

Now I kind of solve the issue by iterating through the column, and do some type checking:

- `df = spark.sql('SELECT col as _col FROM table GROUP BY _col')`
- `df.rdd.map(lambda s: typeChecker(s))`

where in typeChecker I just check which type does `s._col` belongs to.

Thanks.

Comment: A column can not contain more than one type.

Comment: @pault Sorry for the confusion. I don't mean the built in types, the give ones are all strings, but some strings are integers: "1234", or some of them are date/times "2019/11/19".

Comment: Spark allows schema inference (lookup `spark inferSchema`), meaning it can find out for you whether some columns likely contain only integers or floating point numbers or strings. If the columns aren't homogeneous, it will revert to the most generic type that encompasses all found values, usually string. I think you'll get more answers if you shed light on what you're trying to do (the bigger picture). Provide a sample of the data too, to steer discussions.

Comment: @OliverW. Thanks, Oliver. It's my first time sending a post in stack overflow, thank you for your feedback on how to ask questions! btw, I already passed that phase in my project, so I also edit the post to include what I did.